# Blender bones have perpendicular orientation, make them like chain

Tags: rigging, armature

[image]

I opened a rigged model in blender and bones are perpendicular and with offset. Clearing offset makes a mess. What should I do to get bones like in right.

Comment: What format was the file you imported? What import settings did you use?

Comment: format  is FBX, from unity asset store. Import settings I guess default, just import fbx in blender

Comment: Works! Thank you. I checked in checkboxes in import settings. In Armature section, 1) Force connect children 2) Automatic bone orientation.